# asp.net cascading dropdownlists always selects first item

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascading, selectedindexchanged, dropdownlistfor

I am using three DropDownLists in a page. And I am binding data to DDL1(DropDownList1) on pageload using if(!Page.IsPostBack) condition too. And on DDL1 selectedIndexChanged Event I am binding data to DDL2 and its working fine. But when I try to do the same to DDL3 & DDL2 (Like binding data to DDL2 on SelectedIndexChanged Event of DDL2) always DDL2 selects the first item only if I select random also DDL2 still goes first item. Here All 3 DDLs are AutoPostback-true, Vistate-Enabled

***Here is my code:***

**ASPX - Code..**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>    
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />    
</div>
</form>
```

**.CS Code...**

```
public partial class getcolumns : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private SqlConnection con;
private SqlDataAdapter da;
private DataTable dt;
private DataSet ds;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = " SELECT name, dbid FROM sys.sysdatabases where dbid > 4 order by name ";
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["godb"].ToString());
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "name", "dbid");
            //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "dbid";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
        string query = " SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME FROM " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables ";
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["godb"].ToString());
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds; // dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "TABLE_NAME", "TABLE_CATALOG");
        //DropDownList2.DataValueField = "TABLE_CATALOG";
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    }
    catch { }
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
        string query = " SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM  " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = '" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem + "' ";
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["godb"].ToString());
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DropDownList3.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "TABLE_NAME", "COLUMN_NAME");
        //DropDownList3.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME";
        DropDownList3.DataTextField = "COLUMN_NAME";
        DropDownList3.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
}
```

**Edit :-**
It worked well when I Ignore the '*DataValueField*' of DDLs
Thank All to your support...

Comment: try to put your drop downs in `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment. Already I tried with updatePanel but also same result

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Solved - It worked well when I Ignore the '*DataValueField*' of DDLs
Thanks All to your support...

Answer (score 0):

This could be multiple autopostback events, so when it fires firstly ddl1 goes and overwrites selected item in second one. When second event comes it is reset to default state.

You could try using same event method on both and depending on the caller populate stuff.

Make use of these two (object sender, EventArgs e) :D

Comment: hi, thanks for interest on my question. I tried your way of having same Event method for both ddls till the result is same

Comment: protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == DropDownList1) { }
        else if (sender == DropDownList2) { }
    }

Comment: Try this:
var senderDdl = sender as DropDownList;
This makes typecast from object to dropdownlist object, in other words makes 'sender' aware of what it really is. This gives you copy of all properties as in caller object(ddl1/ddl2/...)

Comment: Hi Darko, It worked well when I Ignore the '*DataValueField*' of DDLs
Thanks to your support...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, its working Fine for me.

**aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**.cs**

```
    public List<string> list1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list3 { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
                DropDownList1.DataSource = list1;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            list2 = new List<string> { "1a", "1b", "1c" };
            DropDownList2.DataSource = list2; 
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            list3 = new List<string> { "2a", "2b", "2c" };
            DropDownList3.DataSource = list3;
            DropDownList3.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

I Just removed your default `options` in the dropdowns and removed `viewstatemode` and use your databinding instead of lists.

Comment: Shaminder, Its working as I needed @ Lists, but when go with data-bindings it still the same, and i have tried this too

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_CATALOG"].ToString()));
        }

Comment: Don't use direct connections on page functions, use methods to send `lists` for binding

Comment: Hi Shaminder, It worked well when I Ignore the '*DataValueField*' of DDLs
Thanks to your support...